# SQL/PHP swap values in multiple rows

Tags: php, sql, sqlite

Here's an example database:

```
type | name
-----------------------
B    | John Doe
B    | John Smith
B    | Little Johnny
ZZ   | Mary Jane
ZZ   | Mary's Mom
X    | Tom
```

I want to be able to swap all instances of two given values. Just to further my example, let's swap `B` and `X`.

```
type | name
-----------------------
X    | John Doe
X    | John Smith
X    | Little Johnny
ZZ   | Mary Jane
ZZ   | Mary's Mom
B    | Tom
```

This can't be done with two UPDATE commands because it'll end up setting all of the rows to the same type.

```
UPDATE people SET type="B" WHERE type="X"
UPDATE people SET type="X" WHERE type="B"
```

Yields this unfortunate result:

```
type            | name
-----------------------------------
X               | John Doe
X               | John Smith
X               | Little Johnny
ZZ              | Mary Jane
ZZ              | Mary's Mom
X *should be B* | Tom
```

Comment: Sidenote: Be careful with `type`, it's a MySQL reserved keyword https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html and requires special attention.

Comment: That's no problem, that isn't my actual database :) @Fred-ii-

Comment: I had to point that out. I take posted code literally ;-) You'd be surprised as to how many posts I see where OP's are using reserved words and don't even know it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a temporary value.

For ex:

```
UPDATE people SET type="asdf" WHERE type="X"
UPDATE people SET type="X" WHERE type="B"
UPDATE people SET type="B" WHERE type="asdf"
```

Comment: Duh, don't know how I missed that. Thanks!

Comment: It happens to the best of us.

Answer (score 0):

For this operation you need three state

```
UPDATE people SET type="TMP" WHERE type="X"
UPDATE people SET type="X" WHERE type="B"
UPDATE people SET type="B" WHERE type="TMP"
```